# boundedness of the sequence $a_n=\frac{\sin (n)}{8+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can i prove boundedness of the sequence 
$$a_n=\frac{\sin (n)}{8+\sqrt{n}}$$ without using its convergence to $0$? I know since it is convergent then it is bounded.

Comment: Can you bound its absolute value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\sin (n)| \leq 1$, and $8+\sqrt{n} > 8 \Rightarrow |a_n| < \dfrac{1}{8}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\Big|\frac{sin (n)}{8+\sqrt{n}}\Big|\le\Big|\frac{1}{8+\sqrt{n}}\Big|\le\dfrac{1}{9}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}. $$